# Actualizar un TimePicker en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timepicker

Tengo un ListTile que contiene un TimePicker, que obtiene datos del servidor para ser mostrados al usuario, entre esos datos, está una hora de entrada (y de salida en otro ListTile), esa pantalla en cuestión, es para editar ese registro, y el usuario puede cambiar la hora, seleccionando uno de esos TimePicker y seleccionando la nueva hora, el problema es, que quiero que se despliegue la nueva hora en donde se visualizaba la anterior, pero no he podido hacerlo.

Anexo el código del ListTile:

```
       body: FutureBuilder<FullRecorde>(
          future: futureRecord,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Card(
                //Calendario para seleccionar una fecha.
                child: Column(
                  children: [
  //List Tile que carga la hora de entrada del registro consultado, al presionar, puede asignar una nueva hora.
                    Row(
                      children:const [
                        Text('Entry Time'), 
                      ],
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        //Para que se vea como 17: 0 8
                        "${(formatearHora(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))} : ${(formatearMinutos(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))}",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        
                      ),
                      onTap: _pickEntryTime,
                      //FUNCION DEL TIMEPICKER
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
  //List Tile que carga la hora de salida del registro consultado, al presionar, puede asignar una nueva hora.
                    Row(
                      children: const [
                        Text('Exit Time'),
                      ],
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        //Para que se vea como 17: 0 8
                        "${(formatearHora(snapshot.data!.ExitTime))} : ${(formatearMinutos(snapshot.data!.ExitTime))}",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      onTap: _pickExitTime,
                    ),
```

Y tengo el método del TimePicker:

```
//Función que muestra el Time Picker.
  _pickEntryTime() async {
    TimeOfDay? timeRecord = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: entrytime,
    );
    if (timeRecord != null) {
      setState(() {
        entrytime = timeRecord;
        // DateTime newDateTime = DateTime(time.hour,time.minute);
        finaltime = '${entrytime.hour}:${entrytime.minute}';
        finalfinal = finaltime;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, que campos quieres actualizar?

Comment: Los ListTile que carga la hora para consultar la hora de entrada y salida de un registro, voy a reducir el código del FutureBuilder.

Comment: que hacen las variables que están dentro del setState de pickEntryTime?

Comment: ```entrytime == timerecord``` la uso para guardar el nuevo valor que el usuario seleccione en el timepicker, y quiero poner esos valores en el ListTile, reemplazando el valor cargado anteriormente desde la base de datos (donde dice ```"${(formatearHora(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))} : ${(formatearMinutos(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))}",```).

```finaltime``` y ```finalfinal``` son variables que uso en otro proceso, para darle formato a esa hora y enviarla nuevamente a la base de datos.

Y de hecho, está guardando el valor, pero quiero que se actualice el ListTile en la pantalla.

Comment: cual es la variable que usas para enviar la hora de entrada a la base y cual es a que usas para enviar la hora de salida

Comment: La función _pickEntryTime solo gestiona la hora de entrada, y _pickExitTime la de salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo declararía dos variables de clase que se llamen:

```
String? changeEntryTime;
String? changeFinalTime;
```

Luego a la función para seleccionar la hora le pasaría un parámetro para diferenciar entre la hora de salida y entrada, lo manejaremos por una variable int, donde 0 es entrada y 1 salida:

```
  _pickEntryTime(int id) async {
  TimeOfDay? timeRecord = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: entrytime,
  );
  if (timeRecord != null) {
    setState(() => entrytime = timeRecord);
    if (id == 0) {
      setState(() {
        changeEntryTime = '${entrytime.hour}:${entrytime.minute}';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        changeFinalTime = '${entrytime.hour}:${entrytime.minute}';
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Y ya en los `ListTile` validaría si las variables han sido llenadas, me cambien el valor del `listTile`:

```
    ListTile(
         title: Text(
        changeEntryTime == null ?  
          "${(formatearHora(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))} : 
          ${(formatearMinutos(snapshot.data!.EntryTime))}" : 
          changeEntryTime!,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
        onTap:() => _pickEntryTime(0),             
        ),
     const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
      Row(
          children: const [
             Text('Exit Time'),
             ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        ),
      ListTile(
          title: Text(
              changeFinalTime ? 
                 "${(formatearHora(snapshot.data!.ExitTime))} : 
                 ${(formatearMinutos(snapshot.data!.ExitTime))}" : 
                 changeFinalTime!,
           style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           ),
            onTap:() => _pickEntryTime(1),
         ),
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, debido a que tengo dos funciones, una para la hora de entrada y otra para la hora de salida, no es necesario tener las validaciones, pero funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho.